# How to make calorie goal dynamic in my django app that user can input according to them?

Tags: python, django

**https://github.com/geetanshpardhi1/FitCalorie**

The above link redirects you to my repo where you can find code.
In myapp/index.html (line no.127) I have added functionality for the calorie goal which is hardcoded for value 2000 and I want to make it dynamic for each user, how can I do it?

My doubt is in which model do I have to add a goal field and how can I integrate HTML input with it?